# slider images fading into body background

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slideshow, opacity

This is a hard question to explain so i'm going to use an example. I have my slideshow and what i want to do is fade it at the edges like on this webpage: http://www.gloryworldseries.com/

does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider placing two overlays (left and right) that fade from gray to transparent.

You can make these easily with this little tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/.

To illustrate, I made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tNztZ/) that demonstrates how to position the elements with your CSS.

Comment: that is exactly what im lookin for however, I'm havin trouble puttin it in my code. I'm not sure where in my slideshow css code ive to put it or call it